# Term similar to "gain" for voltage dividers

Tags: voltage-divider

In amplifiers, the magnitude of amplification is called "gain". Is there an equivalent for that on how much a voltage divider divides? Like how a voltage divider with a 100k and 39k resistor has a "divide" of 0.2806.

[image]

I wasn't able to google any results so I've come here. Please let me know if the answer is glaringly obvious.

Comment: it doesn't have a divide of 0.28, it has a divide of about 4, it has a gain (gain=output/input) of 0.28

Comment: Attenuation....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word you may be looking for is "attenuation" or "attenuate".

A voltage divider *attenuates* the input to produce an output that is smaller than the input so, with your 39 kΩ and 100 kΩ resistors, the *attenuation* is: -

$$\dfrac{39+100}{39} = 3.5641$$

In other words, the output is 3.5641 times smaller than the input. Or, the output is *attenuated* by 3.5641 compared to the input.

In gain terms, the gain is the reciprocal of 3.5641 i.e. 0.2806. In other words the output is 0.2806 times the input. So, you can still use the term "gain" but it has a value less than 1 for a voltage divider. Nothing wrong in doing that in fact sometimes, it is slightly less ambiguous to use fractional gain values.

Answer (score 5):

A more general name for the three possible cases (devices) may be "transfer ratio" K = Vout/Vin where:

K < 1 - attenuator,

K = 1 - follower,

K > 1 - amplifier.

It is interesting that, depending on the ratio R2/R1 (R34/R33 in the OP's circuit), the same circuit of an op-amp inverting amplifier can act as an (inverting) attenuator as well as a follower and amplifier:

R2/R1 < 1 - attenuator,

R2/R1 = 1 - follower,

R2/R1 > 1 - amplifier.

Note that the transfer ratio of the voltage divider is R2/(R1 + R2) while the transfer ratio of the inverting amplifier is only -R2/R1. This is because the op-amp removes the resistance R2 (in the denominator of the fraction) by an equivalent negative resistance -R2 so the current flowing through the R1-R2 network depends only on R1 (I = Vin/R1) while, in the case of the voltage follower, it depends both on R1 and R2; I = Vin/(R1 + R2). So the op-amp adds power (voltage) to the passive circuit of a voltage divider thus giving it a chance to amplify (K > 1).

See more about this negative resistance viewpoint in [my RG question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-the-op-amp-in-all-the-inverting-circuits-with-negative-feedback-behave-as-a-negative-impedance-element-negative-resistor-capacitor-etc).